# Leading zeros of partitioned column are lost in Azure Synapse data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a string column in a Synapse data flow that I want to use as a partition column in a parquet file. The data contains leading zeros e.g. `'01'`

The data flow writes this partition correctly, creating a directory with a leading zero:-

[image]

but when I read this file in a subsequent data flow the leading zero is dropped, leaving a value of `'1'`

**How can I prevent this happening?**

I could pad the column, but would prefer if the value was read correctly.

***Extra detail:***

When I preview the data in the sink of the first data flow I see:-
[image]

The partition is created correctly:-

[image]

But when I read the file the leading zero has been 'lost':-
[image]

Both columns show as 'string' under the Projection and Inspect tabs.

Comment: I was under the impression that HDFS honored the leading zeroes, but it seems like Data Flow might be interpreting the value as an int. Can you add screen shots of the Data Flow and the incorrect read?

Comment: Just added some screen shots.

Comment: The Source is correct, because it is finding the leading zeroes. The Sink, however, is base don the data input that happens before it. I see these are new rows to be inserted into the sink - what is generating the value "1" in the data flow?

Comment: The process is:-                                                                                                                "Data flow 1" writes to a partitioned file and the leading zero is retained (as expected). "Data flow 2" reads the file and but drops the leading zero. The second screen shot is the data preview from "Data flow 2"

Comment: Sorry @Bob, I must have read those backwards before. I was able to replicate this issue, but in my data the partition_column column type is registering as numeric. I believe you'll need to add a DerivedColumn to handle this problem.